# Why is javascript showing typeof as "string" when its a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to preform some form validation, and for some reason when I enter a number on the input field it shows  the typeof as a string.

I really can't wrap my head around this. I have tried researching online but couldn't find an answer.

Any help would be really appreciated. Below is my code a link to jsfiddle example.

Thank you in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/eldan88/2xb47g78/

```
<button>Check if number</button>
<input id="number" type="number">

<script>

$("button").click(function () {

    var number = $("#number").val();

    alert(typeof (number));

    if(typeof number !== "number"){
        alert("not a number");
    }




});


</script>
```

Comment: Using `.val()` will always return a string. You can try and parse it as an int first then check it.... `var number = parseInt($("#number").val());`

Comment: @AdamJeffers that won't work - typeof(NaN) is "number". What is needed is the isNaN() function.

Comment: @TAGraves... by "check it" I meant check that it parses as an int... should have been a bit clearer :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the value of an input is always a string. For example, when I'm entering `3`, the actual value is not the number `3`, it is the string `"3"`. To check if it is not a number, use `isNaN()`, a Javascript native function to check if something is not a number. For example, when you run `isNaN("3")` it will return `false`, since `3` is a number.

Comment: Careful; isNaN("") returns false when in this case it looks like it should return true. It's safer to try to convert it to a number with parseFloat() or Number() first.

Comment: TaGraves is correct you need to be careful. Javascript is prone to doing type coercion, so if it is hoping for a number, it will convert a string into a number, etc. But this is a common place people are caught out because coercion is not universal and sometimes it looks fine in one place, but another use of the same value does not coerce, and then things break.

Answer (score 3):

The value property of an input element is always stored as a string, so typeof is always going to return "string".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

You need to write your own custom functions to determine the type of the input.

Comment: Or, use a builtin method like `parseFloat` and see whether it throws an error. Or convert it to a number using `Number(str)` and see whether it returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

The input element with a type attribute whose value is "number" represents a precise control for setting the element’s value to a string representing a number.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

So no matter what, an input contains a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html). it adivses:-

> **value** = floating-point number #
>
> A string representing a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar=5
alert(typeof myVar) //Number

var myVar = "5"
alert(typeof myVar) //String

var myVar = "5"
var vResult = parseInt(myVar);
alert(typeof vResult) //Number
```

In your case what's returned from the text box is .val() which is always a string.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, HTML input elements always store their values as strings, even if those values are "numeric strings." Here's one way of making your validation work:

```js
$("button").click(function () {

    var number = $("#number").val();

    alert(Number(number));

    if(isNaN(Number(number))){
        alert("not a number");
    }

});
```

Comment: `isNaN` thinks `" \t \n \f \r"` is a number.